# IBM MQ Прописать отправку сообщения уведомления в формате XML

Tags: java, ibm, websphere

Есть Java приложение, настроенное на взаимодействие с IBM MQ. Подключение происходит успешно, но чтобы вторую сторону оповестить о наличии файлов в очереди, необходимо её об этом уведомить сообщением в виде файла в формате xml, который содержит переменные значения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой метод здесь можно применить, как это прописать в коде? Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял зачем вы хотите оповещать клиента о наличие сообщений в очереди,  у  клиента и так есть Listener c методом onMessage, который забирает сообщения.
Но если  все-таки такая задача стоит, то можно настроить триггер на глубину очереди и  в этом  триггере прописать  вызов  метода  по  генерации xml/
Но мне кажется я  неправильно вас  понял.